# Date picker does not align in UIKit

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, alignment

When adding the date picker to my view controller, and after adding constraints to the date picker, the alignment of the date picker goes to the right edge. When I change the Preferred Style of the date picker from automatic to compact the alignment goes to the right. The alignment also goes to the right when I run the app and the preferred style is set to automatic. I've also tested with the Attributes Inspector to no success.